# How to create a CF service programatically

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am creating a CF service .

But my service needs to create a another service say abacus for metering . 
Now, When a consumer of my service creates a service instance of my service .

How can my service automatically create the abacus service and bind the abacus service to itself .

Answer (score 0):

You can create and bind a service via [CF API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/3.0.0/service_instances/creating_a_service_instance.html) or use [Java CF Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) to handle the boilerplate.

You need to create UAA client with the needed scopes, act on behalf of a technical user or ask your users to authenticate. Scope "cloud_controller.admin" will certainly do, but you might want to avoid admin access.

Another option is to implement a flow to check your [service user permissions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/dashboard-sso.html#checking-user-permissions)

Abacus Service Broker is synchronous.